# Python - array subset using another array, getting IndexError

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I'm having troubles with the simple task of slicing an array based on another array's values.

I have the array **scores**, with shape:

```
scores.shape = (1, 100, 1)
```

providing confidence scores for 100 detections in every image in a batch (but I'm using a single image, so I only have one element in the batch).
So, for the first and only image, I have values for 100 detection::

```
scores[0] -> [score00, ..., score99]
```

Then, I have another similar array, **bboxes**...for each image in the batch (again, using only one image), and for all the 100 detections in each image, it contains 4 values.
So the shape is:

```
bboxes.shape = (1, 100, 4)
```

For the only image, I have 100 quadruples of values

```
bboxes[0] -> [ [x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max], ..., [x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max] ]
```

and, out of these 100 quadruples, I need to extract only those corresponding to the elements in scores whose value is higher than a certain threshold (0.5).
So, say that only the first 2 scores are higher than the threshold, I would want only the first 2 quadruples.

I'm trying something like:

```
print(bboxes[0][scores[0]>0.5])
```

but I'm getting the error:

```
IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 1; dimension is 4 but corresponding boolean dimension is 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `scores[0]>0.5` is a boolean...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for score, box in zip(scores[0], bboxes[0]):
    if score > 0.5:
        print(box)
```

Comment: Yes, it works, thank you very much! Honestly, I didn't try this way because I was trying to figure out to get the values without using for loops, but I didn't manage to do it yet.